# ifelse is recoding text, but not NAs — I need to recode both

Tags: r, if-statement, recode

I'm trying to recode a variable with mostly NAs and a few text entries to a variable with one of two text entries (as factors). Currently, the variable's entries are either "Fail" or NA. E.g.,

```
AttentionCheck (variable/column)
NA
NA
NA
Fail
NA
NA
Fail
NA
```

I thought that I could use ifelse to tell R to change all the "Fail" entries to a more specific entry ("Failed Attention Check (N = 17)") and change the NAs to "Passed...". So the desired output would be as follows.

```
AttentionCheck (variable/column)
Passed...
Passed...
Passed...
Failed Att...
Passed...
Passed...
Failed Att...
Passed...
```

However, the following ifelse code (and supporting code) does not produce the desired recoding. Specifically, it fails to rename the NAs.

```
> StatVsInd1$AttentionCheck <- as.factor(StatVsInd1$AttentionCheck)
> summary(StatVsInd1$AttentionCheck) # use this to complete the Ns for Pass and fail in next lines
Fail NA's 
  17  246 
> StatVsInd1$AttentionCheck <- ifelse(StatVsInd1$AttentionCheck=="Fail",
+                                     "Failed Attention Check (N = 17)",
+                                     "Passed Attention Check (N = 246)")
> StatVsInd1$AttentionCheck <- as.factor(StatVsInd1$AttentionCheck)
> summary(StatVsInd1$AttentionCheck)
Failed Attention Check (N = 17)                            NA's 
                             17                             246
```

I also (unsuccessfully) tried using ifelse to look for and change the NAs more directly with the following code:

```
StatVsInd1$AttentionCheck <- ifelse(StatVsInd1$AttentionCheck==NA,
                                    "Passed Attention Check (N = 246)",
                                    "Failed Attention Check (N = 17)")
```

I *thought* that this is how I usually recode factors, but apparently I am wrong.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Try using `is.na()` rather than `==NA`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `recode` from dplyr using the `.missing` argument and then convert that to a factor:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
attn <- c(NA, NA, NA, "Fail", NA, NA, "Fail", NA)
factor(recode(attn, .missing = "Passed...", "Fail"="Failed Att..."))
#> [1] Passed...     Passed...     Passed...     Failed Att... Passed...    
#> [6] Passed...     Failed Att... Passed...    
#> Levels: Failed Att... Passed...
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

[John Harley's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62685150/ifelse-is-recoding-text-but-not-nas-i-need-to-recode-both/62685347#comment110854260_62685150) worked. Specifically, the following code produced the desired output:

```
> StatVsInd1$AttentionCheck <- ifelse(is.na(StatVsInd1$AttentionCheck),
+                                     "Passed Attention Check (N = 246)",
+                                     "Failed Attention Check (N = 17)")
> StatVsInd1$AttentionCheck <- as.factor(StatVsInd1$AttentionCheck)
> summary(StatVsInd1$AttentionCheck)
 Failed Attention Check (N = 17) Passed Attention Check (N = 246) 
                              17                              246
```